# Flex WebService using WSDL. How to list available operations?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, web-services, wsdl

I'm using WebService class with WSDL.

How to list available operations in WSDL and their parameters?

There is [operations](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/AbstractService.html#operations) property but it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posted: http://blog.comtaste.com/2010/03/flex_webservice_how_to_list_av.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not just go to the WSDL in your browser to see the functions available? I don't believe its built into Flex to list out the available operations for you

Comment: The question was "How to list available operations in WSDL and their parameters?"

Comment: Its possible by going to the WSDL link in your browser... I don't think you can do it from within Flex Builder. I.E http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

Comment: "I don't think you can do it from within Flex Builder. "  meaning Flex Builder will not tell you what operations are available nor what parameters to pass.

Comment: It seems like it would be useful to have this feature. About WSDL from browser is obvious. I can parse WSDL file as XML but I thought that it should be something built-in. In other languages you can list operations, parameters and their types. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I certainly agree.. Looks like their working it into Flash Builder 4 http://srinivasannam.wordpress.com/2009/06/03/using-webservice-dcd/

Comment: Wait... could be wrong lol (sorry I dont have Flex on this computer)... check this out http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_ws.html